# Web Scraper isn't filling up the .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, twitter

Wrote a simple web scraping script to parse a certain news channel for their tweet. So I wanted it to parse those tweets and write it in a `.csv` file. The script seems to be working fine but I just can't figure out how to make it write "tweets" and the "news_link" under their respective headers!

What am I missing?

#### Code:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
import csv

source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://twitter.com/abpnewstv").read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

with open("twitter news.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    news_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    news_writer.writerow(["tweet", "news_link"])

for content in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "js-tweet-text-container"}):
    tweet = content.p.text.split(".")[0]
    print(tweet)
    try:
        news_link = content.a.text
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    print(news_link + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform two more steps

1. Write each tweet like:

   ```
    news_writer.writerow([tweet, news_link])
   ```
2. Make sure this is done under the context manager for the open csv file.

#### Full Listing:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
import csv

source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://twitter.com/abpnewstv").read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

with open("twitter news.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    news_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    news_writer.writerow(["tweet", "news_link"])

    for content in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "js-tweet-text-container"}):
        tweet = content.p.text.split(".")[0]
        print(tweet)
        try:
            news_link = content.a.text
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        print(news_link + "\n")

        news_writer.writerow([tweet, news_link])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not writing anything to the csv file besides the header - you're just printing to stdout. You need to indent your `for` loop within the `with` block and use `news_writer.writerow([tweet, news_link])` instead of printing.